# Best method for continually adding new data to listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have managed to successfully write a service that downloads data from an `RSS` feed, parses it, and save it to a database.  I also have an activity fragment which uses the cursor loader technique to retrieve all data rows and displays them on screen in a horizontal `listview` I scavenged off the internet.

My next mission is to modify the activity so that I can continually query for the next `x` number of rows every time the user scrolls to near the end of the listview and add them to the `listview`.  Technically my data is small enough that if I showed 10 rows at startup, I could probably just query for 20 and reset the adapter - but it seems silly to have to re-query the same rows repeatedly.

So essentially my main question is: how best would I combine the currently held `listview` contents populated with a `Cursor/CursorAdapter` with the results of a fresh query using the `LoaderCallbacks`?

Secondly, what is the correct syntax for the limit parameter of the `SQLiteQueryBuilder`?  I have tried many variations although I think a string of "`offset, maxrows`" is correct?  No matter what I provide though I am always getting 0 from `getCount()` on my cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an ArrayList of your items inside your Adapter, when you have new items to display, just create a method to insert them into the ArrayList.

Question about SQL you can find on that link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html
you have to add the limit on then method buildQuery, if that doesn't work, please paste here your code

Comment: The link to the developer reference doesn't tell me how to format the clause - except to say 'formatted as LIMIT clause'.  Google tells me sqlite has two options for the limit clause: 'limit x offset y' and 'limit y,x'.  In my testing including the word limit causes the query to fail with a syntax error where at least a string of 'y,x' does not.  It does not produce a correct getCount value though - or data on the screen.

Comment: ah, limit clause was my fault - the rest of my query wasn't correct.  As soon as I fixed that the limit clause works perfectly as explained above.